# Java regex to preserve ngrams in square brackets

Tags: java, regex, n-gram

I am a bit of a newbie with Java regex so I wonder if anyone can help where I need a regex to split text based on ngrams. So if I have text like this:

`dyson [salisbury matheson beaumont] clarke [carstairs morden] vaughan`

To return the following ngrams:

`Unigram:   dyson
Trigram:   salisbury matheson beaumont
Unigram:   clarke
Bigram:    carstairs morden
Unigram:   vaughan`

The contents of the square brackets are preserved as bigrams or trigrams?

The split would be based upon spaces outside the brackets.

Comment: what happens if you have something like "dyson [salisbury matheson beaumont] clarke davidson [carstairs morden] vaughan"?

Comment: clarke and davidson are unigrams.

Comment: so the result would be something like ["dyson", "salisbury matheson beaumont", "clarke", "davidson", "carstairs morden", "vaughan"]?  that's what I thought, but it isn't terribly clear from your question... I almost downvoted before I realized what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

```
\w+|\[([\w\s]+)\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL3eH3/2)

Explanation:

- `\w+` matches a word (a series of alphanumeric characters or an underscore)
- or: `\[([\w\s]+)\]`

  - `\[` matches a `[`
  - `[\w\s]+` matches a series of words and spaces, this is captured
  - `\]` matches a `]`

If you have a capture it means you have something in brackets, else it means you have a single word. You can then apply the simple `\w+` regex to the contents of the brackets to extract the words.

To use it in Java you have to escape the backslashes to pass them as-is to the regex engine:

```java
String pattern = "\\w+|\\[([\\w\\s]+)\\]";
```

Comment: Thanks but if I try `String delimiters = "\w+|(?:\[([\w\s]+)\]";` I get an illegal escape char message. I want to use this line in a `split` like this: `String[] ngrams = ngramsText.split(delimiters);`

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes when passing the string to Java: `String pattern = "\\w+|(?:\\[([\\w\\s]+)\\]";`. And don't use the `split` function, it's a bad fit for this case. Use matching instead.

Comment: Although I had to add an extra `)` to the regex to make it `String pattern = "\\w+|(?:\\[([\\w\\s]+))\\]";`. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes is a typo in my comment above, sorry about that. Actually the grouping construct is superfluous, so you can just write: `String pattern = "\\w+|\\[([\\w\\s]+)\\]";`